# wrap image with next link

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a slideshow for upcoming events. The slides are suppose to link to their corresponding event page. But, not all slides are suppose to have a link if they don't have an event page.

Here is the HTML I'm able to output:

```
 <ul>
  <li><img><a href="/link1">link1</a></li>
  <li><img><a href="/link2">link2</a></li>
  <li><img></li> // this one doesn't have a link
 </ul>
```

Then with jQuery I'm trying to change that HTML to look like this:

```
 <ul>
  <li><a href="/link1"><img></a></li>
  <li><a href="/link2"><img></a></li>
  <li><img></li> // this one doesn't have a link
 </ul>
```

Here is the jQuery I've been working on:

```
$(function() {

    $(' ul li img').each(function() { // For each image

        if($(' ul li img').next('a').attr("href").length) // check if banner has a link

        var a = $(this).next('a').attr("href"); // Find its associated anchor and give a name

        $(' ul li img').wrap('<a href="' + a + '"></a>'); // And wrap the image

        return false;

});
```

This just seems to take the first href and wrap every image with the same href.

Comment: How do you determine if the image has a link or not?

Comment: This if statement: if($(' ul li img').next('a').attr("href").length) checks if there is an <a> tag.

Comment: Why is the a tag there? Do you control the html or can't you change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(' ul li img')` returns array, so in `.each(funtion(){})` you must use `$( this )` which returns current `img` in array.

You code must looks like this:

```
$(' ul li img').each(function() { // For each image
  var $a = $(this).next('a').attr("href");
  if($a.length){ // check if banner has a link
    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + $a + '"></a>'); // And wrap the image
  }
});
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<a href ...>` and wrap it later I'd suggest to give an data attribute to your image, check for that and if there is one, add an event listener to link to the intended page.

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i<images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i].getAttribute('data-link')) {
        images[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
            /* this is what you want to do:
            window.location.href=this.getAttribute('data-link'); */
            // just for the effect here:
            alert(this.getAttribute('data-link'));
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg" data-link="http://www.google.com"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/286.jpg" data-link="http://www.twitter.com"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/138.jpg"></li> 
 </ul>
```